# JSON object is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes and customType

Tags: reactjs, typescript, exception

I'm trying to read in JSON data into an array of type **pinImage**.
Then loop/map thru my pinImage objects and pass each one to a child component PinCard which is setup to take in an object of type pinImage.

I'm stumped after reading several other stackOverflow posts and am hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve this.

Currently I get this exception:
Type '{ pinData: { id: number | undefined; name: string; description: string; category: string; img: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & pinImage'.
Property 'pinData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & pinImage'.

High level I think this means that it's getting extra properties and doesn't know how to pass in the data, but I cannot figure out how to resolve this.

PinImage.tsx aka my custom type:

```
export type pinImage = {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    img: string;
};
```

PinCard.tsx aka my child component:

```
import { pinImage } from "../Type/PinImage";

function PinCard(pinData : pinImage){
    return(
        <div>img src = {pinData.img} alt="{pinData.description}"</div>
    )
}

export default PinCard;
```

PinCardList.tsx aka my parent component, it reads in json data and tries to pass that to child, this fails with the before posted exception.

```
import data from '../Data/PinRepo.json';
import PinCard from '../PinCard/PinCard';
import { pinImage } from '../Type/PinImage';

function PinCardList(){     
    let dataList : pinImage[] = data.pin;

    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    dataList.map((item) => {
                        return <li key={item.id}><PinCard pinData={item}/></li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PinCardList;
```

PinRepo.json aka my json data that I'm passing using

```
{
    "pin": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name":"WowHead 15th Anniversary rocket",
            "description" : "Wowhead 15th Anniversary rocket",
            "category": "Wowhead",
            "img": "..\\..\\src\\Images\\Pins\\wowhead_rocket_15anniversary.PNG"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name":"WowHead Alliance rocket",
            "description" : "Wowhead Alliance rocket",
            "category" : "Wowhead",
            "img": "..\\..\\src\\Images\\Pins\\wowhead_rocket_alliance.PNG"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name":"WowHead Horde rocket",
            "description" : "Wowhead Horde rocket",
            "category" : "Wowhead",
            "img": "..\\..\\src\\Images\\Pins\\wowhead_rocket_horde.PNG"
        },        
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "name":"Wowhead Torghast rocket",
            "description" : "Wowhead Torghast rocket",
            "category" : "Wowhead",
            "img": "..\\..\\src\\Images\\Pins\\wowhead_rocket_torghast.PNG"
        }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately I am not sure if what I'm doing above is viable.

I eventually got my json data to convert with the use of an interface instead of type.  I'm still interested in other's answers if anyone wants to share, otherwise here's the changes I made to give a defined structure to my json and to pass it from a parent to child object.

Defined an interface.  I used this website after looking at it being suggested in a youtube video.  https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript.  The main thing I got from this is that for a collection of objects you can do **export type CollectionName = SingleObject[]**

```
export type Pins = Pin[]

export interface Pin {
  id: number
  name: string
  description: string
  category: string
  img: string
}
```

In PinCard I imported the Pin interface and defined a PinCardProps interface (I dug a bit more thru the internet and one of the things I saw that worked is defining an interface for your function props.

```
import { Pin } from "../Interface/Pin";

interface PinCardProps { 
    pin : Pin;
}

function PinCard(pinData: PinCardProps){
    return(
        <div>img src = {pinData.pin.img} alt="{pinData.pin.description}"</div>
    )
}

export default PinCard;
```

In PinCardList I used my interface.  The main key that resulted in things working for me is that prop interface defined on the child component because now I can do "PinCard **pin**= {item}" which was the last piece to get things to work for me.

```
import data from '../Data/PinRepo.json';
import PinCard from '../PinCard/PinCard';
import { Pins } from '../Interface/Pin'; 

function PinCardList(){     
    let dataList : Pins = data;

    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    dataList.map((item) => {
                        return <li key={item.id}><PinCard pin={item}/></li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PinCardList;
```